# SharePoint 2016 - Product / patch installation or server upgrade required

Tags: 2016, health-analyzer

This is a production SharePoint 2016 MinRole farm with 2 servers (AppSearch & FEDistCache).
After a network outage, in the Health Report I am getting the following configuration Error:

> Title: Product / patch installation or server upgrade required.
>
> Explanation: All required products must be installed on all servers in
>   the farm, and all products should have the same patching and upgrade
>   level across the farm. Upgrade is required on server FEDistCache.
>   Without the upgrade, the server is not in a supported state.

Fact: It needs to get updated to a recent KB but I want to get this resolved before I do an upgrade.

Things I have tried/reviewed:

- rebooted both servers
- Reanalyze Now after rebooting the servers but Error keeps showing up under review problems and solutions.
- compared Windows update between both MinRole servers and they are the same
- On Manage Patch Status both servers have the same version installed and same KB
- On Servers in Farm, Status = No Action Required for both servers.
- Upgrade Status = Succeeded on the last update.

Is there any troubleshooting that I could do to resolve this without running an upgrade on the farm?

Comment: Get-spproduct in powershell might help your servers. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/08/09/sharepoint-patching-and-get-spproduct-local/

Comment: Check the status of DC, use-cachecluster , Get-cachehost, make sure they are up and running

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP I checked and AppFabricCachingService is UP; Status: Online

Comment: did you ran the get-spproduct? also make sure, Farm admin account & app pool accounts have the proper permission on the Content Databases, config databases

Comment: @Christoffer get-spproduct is used when patching SharePoint, based on that link that you posted and in this case I don't want to patch the servers, I would prefer to resolve this error first. I was thinking if that particular server might be out of sync with the config DB.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP I haven't ran get-spproduct because I am not patching the farm. I understand that if I run that I trigger an update, right? Checked Pool and Farm account permissions and content and config dbs and they have same permissions as my test farm which is not having that issue.

Comment: Get-spproduct will not trigger any update rather it give you information....on back end it basically sync the config db.

Comment: I ran: 
$spprod = Get-SPProduct
$spprod.Servers | select ServerName, Products, InstallStatus 
#the result was InstallStatus = NoActionRequired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue auto resolved. Logged into Central Admin as the farm account and clicked Reanalyze Now and got a Success. Nothing was changed and I didn't run get-spproduct.